# lli.exe: Failed to materialize symbols

Tags: c++, winapi, clang, llvm, lli

I am trying to compile a program that spawns a windows messagebox to llvm IR. And then execute it with `lli`.

This is the program:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI main() {
    MessageBox(NULL, "Hello, World!", "Hello", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it like this:
`clang++ -S -emit-llvm .\main.cpp -o main.ll`

But when I try to run it from `lli` I get this error:

```
JIT session error: Symbols not found: [ MessageBoxA ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\LLVM\bin\lli.exe: Failed to materialize symbols: { (main, { main, ??_C@_05COLMCDPH@Hello?$AA@, ??_C@_0O@KLMCIIGF@Hello?0?5World?$CB?$AA@ }) }
```

If I check the `lli` process in a debugger I see user32.dll is loaded.
But I feel I am missing something fundamentally.
Since When I compile my program as a regular exe I need to specify `-luser32`
Using the `-load` flag with the path to user32.dll also doesnt help.
Can anyone help me execute my messagebox program in `lli`